# centering a div even if the contents is wider than the screen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is similar to other questions asked, but with one extra issue and I can't find anyone with the same problem as me.

I have an image which is 1400px wide and which I want to be centred in the middle of the page even if the user is looking through a browser with a 800px resolution.

I can't use a BackGround image because I need to rotate this image with a few others using the jquery cycle plugin.

The way I found to centre an image by using:

```
div.slideshowWrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
  div.slideshowWrap div.homeslideshow {
  position: relative;
  width: 10000px;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 0 0 -5000px;
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="slideshowWrap">
    <div class="homeslideshow">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('background_01.jpg');?>
    </div>
</div>
```

works, but when I add the extra slides required for the jquery cycle it messes up the positioning...

```
<div class="slideshowWrap">
    <div class="homeslideshow">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('background_01.jpg');?>
    </div>
    <div class="homeslideshow">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('background_02.jpg');?>
    </div>
    <div class="homeslideshow">
        <?php echo $this->Html->image('background_03.jpg');?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to sort this out? There doesn't seem to be a way to centre images, only backgrounds. But there's no way to fade in and out backgrounds like the jquery cycle plugin allows.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Is the class `.homeslideshow` in the center already?

Comment: In the first example, when there's only 1 background image, then .homeslideshow is in the center. If I add more images like in the 2nd example then it all goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.homeslidshow { 
    position: relative; /* if there is no position applied already */
}

.homeslideshow > img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    /* and your width here */
}
```

I had seen this technique in a recent post.

Comment: This isn't working for me. My problem is about using the jquery cycle plugin too. :(